# difference in loading the property file with pom.xml and creating a placeholder in applicationContext.xml

Tags: java, spring-mvc, maven-3

i have a property file which is loaded based on the environment. I have created a placeholder in applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:environment-${buildProfile}.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

There is a another way to load this file through Maven.

could you please suggest me which is the better way to load a property file? is there any performance difference in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a big difference between the two. Mainly, when you use filters in Maven to do property replacement, the placeholder is *physically replaced* in the file by the desired value. So, your deployed artifact has the configuration "baked in" so to speak. Using Spring's property placeholders, however, allows you to load those properties at runtime. This allows you to deploy your artifact and delay configuration until runtime. It really depends on your business case, but my personal preference is to avoid Maven filtering as much as possible and instead rely on runtime configuration, simply because I like to produce a single artifact from a Maven build, and if you alter the properties based on, for example, the environment you are targeting, you have to produce a different artifact for each environment. A single artifact for all environments, with a runtime-loaded configuration that may differ for each environment (like dev, qa, and production) makes for a cleaner deployment. It also allows you to configure potentially sensitive properties, such as password for database connectivity, on a server where there is limited access so that a limited number of people are privy to such sensitive information.